Docker container doesn't use the right cuda version
I am trying to run an old application that uses python3.6 and tensorflow 2.3.0.
As I want to use the GPU, I need Cuda 10.1. However, it is not supported on ubuntu 22.04.
To overcome this issue, I used the following docker container
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# Définir debconf pour fonctionner en mode non interactif
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y \
    && apt-get install -y git build-essential \
    python3 python3-pip gcc wget \
    software-properties-common \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804_10.1.105-1_amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1804_10.1.105-1_amd64.deb

RUN apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
RUN apt-key adv --fetch-keys http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/3bf863cc.pub

# Mettre à jour et installer CUDA
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    cuda-10-1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    nvidia-driver-418

COPY libcudnn7_7.6.3.30-1+cuda10.1_amd64.deb /tmp/libcudnn7.deb

RUN dpkg -i /tmp/libcudnn7.deb 

RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/*

ENV PATH /usr/local/cuda-10.1/bin:${PATH}
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}

However, when I execute "nvidia-smi" INSIDE the container, I get :
# nvidia-smi
Tue Jun  4 02:54:00 2024       
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 545.23.06              Driver Version: 545.23.06    CUDA Version: 12.3     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 ...    On  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   42C    P0              28W / 115W |     10MiB /  8192MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+


That is my host machine configuration.
Did someone already have the same issue?
Thanks you!
I was expecting to use Cuda 10.1 with the drivers 418.
Note that when I type nvcc --version, I get
nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Jul_28_19:07:16_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243

Which is correct

The CUDA version shown by nvidia-smi is a driver compatibility indicator. Nothing more
